# How can I have more than one project inside IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA.

In Eclipse I have many Java projects I can open and see the code I need. However, in IntelliJ IDEA I can see only one project at a time.

How can I have more than one project in the IDEA IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open more than one project in the IDEA IDE.

In IntelliJ IDEA, you go to File -> New -> Module from Existing Source...
You can refer image to see:

[image]

After import your project. You will see result as image:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This ...

> In Eclipse I have many Java projects I can open and see the code I need

... refers to an Eclipse Workspace. There is no direct equivalent to Workspaces in IntelliJ.

IntelliJ provides a help topic titled [Migrating From Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html) which maps Eclipse concepts to IntelliJ concepts. In particular, it has this to say about the absence of Workspaces from IntelliJ ...

> The first thing you'll notice when launching IntelliJ IDEA is that it has no workspace concept. This means that you can work with only one project at a time. While in Eclipse you normally have a set of projects that may depend on each other, in IntelliJ IDEA you have a single project that consists of a set of modules.
>
> If you have several unrelated projects, you can open them in separate windows.
>
> If you still want to have several unrelated projects opened in one window, as a workaround you can configure them all in IntelliJ IDEA as modules.

Comment: Yes, but how ? How can I configure them as modules ?

Comment: That text is taken from the [linked](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html) IntelliJ docs. I suspect it is referring to a situation where your Java projects belong to a single parent (e.g. a multi module Maven project). In this case, you would import the parent and each sub project will appear as a distinct module within IntelliJ.